# How to prevent React-Final-Form to reset the form values after user submits the form?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, react-final-form

I am using `react-final-form` in React App. It's working great!

But is there any way to prevent the `react-final-form` from resetting the input values of the form after user successfully submit the form.

Reason why I need it because, currently when the user is redirected after submitted the form, user see input values being reset to initial form values for `200-400 micro second` between the action of submitting the form and redirecting to other component.

I tried using following but didn't work:

> e.preventDefault();
>
> return false;

Following is the function that handles the form submission.

```
export const useCreateAgent = (
  onCompleted: () => void,
) => {
  const [createAgent] = useMutation(CREATE_AGENT, {
    onCompleted,
  });

  return useCallback(async (agent: IAgent) => {
    try {
      await createAgent(createVariables({ ...agent }));
    } catch (errors) {
      return errors;
    }
  }, [createAgent]);
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`keepDirtyOnReinitialize` prop fixed that issue.

```
<Form keepDirtyOnReinitialize >
   ...
</Form>
```

Comment: Thanks lot Ishan Patel. Save me from lot of trouble.

Answer (score 0):

If it is just a question about the looks between submission and new page:

event.persist() prevents React from resetting the event object.

Comment: That doesn't seem to persist the data. I have tried to use it.